# Python: Why would a Process stay alive even after it finished its run()

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have a multiprocessing program that launched a group of Processes. The `run()` part of these programs are like this:

```
def run(self):
    self.prep()
    self._prn('Started with PID {pid}'.format(pid=self.pid))
    while True:
        job = self._queue.get()
        if job is None: break
        self.do_work(**job)
    self._prn('Received spindown signal.')
```

(The `_prn` method simply prepends the name of the Process, like this:)

```
def _prn(self, *args, **kwargs):
    print('{nam}({pid}):'.format(nam=self.name, pid=self.pid), end='')
    print(*args, **kwargs)
```

Job parameters are sent by pushing a dict into the queue.

So upon completion, I pushed several `None`s into the queue, and I see the Process-es all printing out `Received spindown signal.`.

However, for inexplicable reasons, even though I saw a Process has emitted the `Received spindown signal` message, they kept being alive! (That is, their `.is_alive()` method keep returning `True`)

This is the polling code I'm using:

```
while len(workers) > 0:
    still_alives = []
    for w in workers:
        if w.is_alive():
            still_alives.append(w)
        else:
            prn('    {nam} trying to join...'.format(nam=w.name))
            w.join()
            prn('    {nam} joined.'.format(nam=w.name))
    prn('  Still alive:', ' '.join((w.name for w in still_alives)))
    workers = still_alives
    time.sleep(10)
```

This is an excerpt of the output I'm seeing:

```
Main:  Still alive: Querier-0 Querier-2 Querier-3 Querier-4 Querier-6 Querier-7 Querier-9 Querier-10
Querier-9:Received spindown signal.
Querier-4:Received spindown signal.
Main::    Querier-4 trying to join...
Main::    Querier-4 joined.
Main::    Querier-9 trying to join...
Main::    Querier-9 joined.
Main::  Still alive: Querier-0 Querier-2 Querier-3 Querier-6 Querier-7 Querier-10
Querier-3:Received spindown signal.
Querier-10:Received spindown signal.
Querier-6:Received spindown signal.
Main::  Still alive: Querier-0 Querier-2 Querier-3 Querier-6 Querier-7 Querier-10
Main::  Still alive: Querier-0 Querier-2 Querier-3 Querier-6 Querier-7 Querier-10
Querier-0:Received spindown signal.
Main::  Still alive: Querier-0 Querier-2 Querier-3 Querier-6 Querier-7 Querier-10
Main::  Still alive: Querier-0 Querier-2 Querier-3 Querier-6 Querier-7 Querier-10
```

As you can see, `Querier-4` and `-9` dies properly. But `Querier-3`, `-10`, `-6`, and `-0` never died!

What is going on here?

Comment: Sanity check the queue on both sides; if it's not empty those processes wont terminate. Also, this might help (if you haven't already gone over it) https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html#programming-guidelines

Comment: @willnx ha, very likely suspect. Let me do some investigation. Thanks for the pointer. I'll get back to you...

Comment: @willnx I think you're right! So I rewrote the cleanup code to 'drain' the queues first before attempting to join() them, and the child processes now die properly! If you can rewrite your comment as an Answer, I'll mark it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking the queue from both sides; if it's not empty then the process wont terminate.

Also, I found this  [link](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html#programming-guidelines) really handy when debugging some multiprocessing issues.